# Cannot read property 'resize' of undefined state image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have image state:

```
class imageUpload extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      image: null
    }
```

in my return I have this on change:

```
<input type="file" id="select" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
```

and this code to get the image...

```
 handleChange = e => {
    if (e.target.files[0]) {
      const image = e.target.files[0];
      this.setState(() => ({image}));
          {this.upload()}
    }
  }
  handleUpload = () => {
      const {image} = this.state;
  }

upload = () => {
    ImageTools.resize(this.state.image, { //TypeError: Cannot read property 'resize' of undefined
        width: 320,
        height: 240
    }, function(blob, didItResize) {
        document.getElementById('preview').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${this.state.image.name}`).put(blob);
      uploadTask.on('state_changed', 
      (snapshot) => {
```

why this.state.image is giving me `TypeError: Cannot read property 'resize' of undefined` when I select an image?

how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly note that you component name should be uppercased `ImageUpload` or React will think it's a DOM element.

Because `this.setState` is async, on calling `this.upload` straight after `setState` will use the current state value which is `image: null`.

If you depend on state, you may want to try:

```
this.setState({image});
this.state.image && this.upload();
```

Or use the actual `image` value:

```
// use image argument in upload
this.upload(image);
```

Or if you trying to use `upload` **after** updating the state, you may want to try the [`callback` argument of `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

```
// setState(updater, [callback])
this.setState({ image }, this.upload(image));
```

Comment: thanks a lot. to get the image value I use `upload = img => {
    ImageTools.resize(img, {` ??? img is null too...

Comment: It can't be `null`... You using a condition beforehand `if (e.target.files[0])`

Comment: sorry, not nul... gives me the same error: `Cannot read property 'resize' of undefined`

Comment: So maybe `ImageTools` is `undefined`, you better ask a new question because it is not related